# How to plot a 3-D risk plane in R?

Tags: r, matrix, plot, 3d, survival-analysis

I am trying to plot a risk plane in a 3-D plot in R to graphically depict effect modification of a continuous predictor on the association between some other continuous predictor and an outcome. The risk estimates (HR, hazard ratio) should be on the z-axis and the two continuous predictor variables on the x- and y-axis, like in the plot below:

[image]

To illustrate what I have already tried, I will make use of the `lung` data set from the `survival` package.

```
#install.packages("survival")
#install.packages("rgl")

library(survival); library(rgl)

#Remove missing values with listwise deletion
I1 <- is.na(lung$age) | is.na(lung$ph.karno)
lung <- lung[!I1,]

m1 <- coxph(Surv(time, status==2) ~ age*ph.karno, data = lung)
m1

z <- outer(lung$age, lung$ph.karno, FUN=function(x=lung$age, y=lung$ph.karno, model=m1){
  ref.x <- median(x)
  ref.y <- median(y)
  for(i in 1:length(x)){
    exp(summary(model)$coef[1,1]*(x[i]-ref.x)+summary(model)$coef[2,1]*(y[i]-ref.y)+
               summary(model)$coef[3,1]*(x[i]-ref.x)*(y[i]-ref.y))
  }
})

persp3d(x=lung$age, y=lung$ph.karno, z=z)
```

With `exp(summary(model)$coef[1,1]*(x[i]-ref.x)+summary(model)$coef[2,1]*(y[i]-ref.y)+summary(model)$coef[3,1]*(x[i]-ref.x)*(y[i]-ref.y))` I aimed to manually calculate the hazard ratio according to

[image]

with the median age and karnofsky score (ph.karno) set as the respective references. However when I run this code, I encounter the following two errors:
`Error in dim(robj) <- c(dX, dY) : attempt to set an attribute on NULL` after running the function within `outer()` and `Error in persp3d.default(x = lung$age, y = lung$ph.karno, z = z) : Increasing 'x' and 'y' values expected`.

Does anyone know how to obtain such a plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use something along these lines. First we fint the model as per your own code:

```
library("survival"); library("rgl")

#Remove missing values with listwise deletion
I1 <- is.na(lung$age) | is.na(lung$ph.karno)
lung <- lung[!I1,]

m1 <- coxph(Surv(time, status==2) ~ age*ph.karno, data = lung)
m1
```

Then use the `predict()` function to compute the risk from the model. As the model includes an interaction this is automatically included in the prediction. As input we use appropriately spaced values in the observed ranges of `age` and `ph.karno`.

```
age.range <- seq(min(lung$age), max(lung$age), 5)
ph.range <- seq(min(lung$ph.karno), max(lung$ph.karno), 5)

z <- outer(age.range, ph.range, FUN=function(x, y) {
  predict(m1, newdata = data.frame(age=x, ph.karno=y), type="risk")
  })

rgl::persp3d(age.range, ph.range, z, col="lightblue")
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I am still wondering what the construct would look like when the interaction is adjusted for additional variables, for instance: `m2 <- coxph(Surv(time, status==2) ~ age*ph.karno + sex + wt.loss, data = lung)`

Comment: As long as you are only considering interactions between two predictors then the other variables are essentially irrelevant (for illustrating the interaction). They will just scale the overall risk up or down. For more than two predictors you'd have to split your data up *or* plot in 4D :o)